I want to merge excel files with the same format but different numerical values, the generated excel file is corrupted
When I try to merge Excel files, the spaces and colors do not merge correctly. The formats in the excel files I uploaded are the same headings etc. Only numeric values are different. But the excel file created is nested or incomplete.
If the locations of the numeric values in the excel files I am trying to combine match, I want the result to be collected and printed. If there is no matching data with other excel files, it should write as it is. But the format must be the same. I don't know much about the Exceljs library, I have only exported json data so far.
